# Javascript code block not working with other page

Tags: javascript, css

I have some problem with my JavaScript code that I need help from you

#### index.html

```html
<body>
   <button class="dark">Dark</button>
   <p>First Page</p>
</body>
```

#### second-page.html

```html
<body>
   <p>Second Page</p>
</body>
```

#### main.css

```css
root{
  --bg-color: white;
}

.dark{
   --bg-color: black;
}

body{
   background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

#### main.js

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('dark')
const body = document.body

btn.addEventListener('click',function (){
  body.classList.toggle('dark')
  if(body.classList.contains("dark")){
    localStorage.setItem("mode","dark")
  }
  else{
    localStorage.setItem("mode","light")
  }
});

if(localStorage.getItem('mode') == "dark"){
  body.classList.toggle('dark')
};
```

All of my Html page I was link with the same javascript page but my index.html is working normal but my Second page(seceond-page.html) is not working, because in this page there is no class name "dark".
and I also have some solve but that not logic and I need more code block for my html page from that file.

My solve is **Change line that define a variable**

```js
const body = document.body;

if (localStorage.getItem('mode') == 'dark') {
  body.classList.toggle('dark');
}

const toggleMode = document.querySelector('.theme-icon');
toggleMode.addEventListener('click', function () {
  body.classList.toggle('dark');
  if (body.classList.contains('dark')) {
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');
  }
});
```

Comment: If you want to have separate files you will need to copy most of html between these files

Comment: Your code is incomplete and there is no button with id dark, only a classname.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `btn` variable usage in an `if` condition before doing anything with it;

```
if(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click',function(){});
}
```

This way, if the `#dark` element doesn't exist, the code wont run.

Also, your way of making a dark mode logic is a bit flawed. It can be made very simple. Like https://dev.to/codedgar/how-to-create-a-dark-theme-system-in-5-minutes-or-less-with-vanilla-js-2922

Comment: You can also use `?.` operator